# How do you use a Font Awesome icons with FineUploader's image previews?

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome, fine-uploader

Fine Uploader supports image previews. Their API also supports [thumbnail placeholders](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-ui.html#thumbnails.placeholders). It requires, however, a relative or full image URL. Is it possible to supply an HTML element or raw HTML instead?

I'd like to simply use Font Awesome for a generic document placeholder or "image generation in progress."

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to replace fine uploader's default image placeholders? If so, with what, specifically? Please don't answer with "font awesome" or raw html. The images you want to use are represented as pure CSS, SVG, or some image file referenced via a data or traditional uri. Which of these describe your intended replacement placeholders?

Comment: @RayNicholus Font Awesome uses a font file + CSS `content`. [Font Awesome source](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/css/font-awesome.css#L7). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fine Uploader requires placeholder images be actual images. So you will need to supply a URI (data or otherwise) to your desired placeholder images. If you need Fine Uploader to support a different workflow, please open up a [feature request](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/new) with a *detailed* description of the *exact* adjustments you are looking for, complete with a full description of the workflow.